# Criticality broken (SMS & Call log) Permission Declaration form while uploading an app on thge Play store

Tags: android

In my app, I was using SmsManager for sending SMS, but now google play updates their permission policy and Google Play restricts the use of high risk or sensitive permissions, including the SMS or Call Log permission groups.

Comment: Does this not just mean that you have to ask users for more permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't take sms or permission without submitting proper purpose. If your purpose to compose a message and display the composed message in users' write message. Then no need to add message permision in manifest. In this process you can just compose a message , reciepient numbers but sending options will be in users hand.. Follow the code below:

```
private void sendMessage(String messageToSend) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:+8801714262873");
        //for multiple numbers 
        // Uri uri =Uri.parse("smsto:+8801714262873,+8801877014379");
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        it.putExtra("sms_body", messageToSend);
        startActivity(it);
    }
```